# How to define a constraint for one-bit random variable?

Tags: constraints, system-verilog

In my case, if the value of a bit is "1", then my constraint will have a higher weight for '1'.  If the bit is "0", then my constraint will have higher weight for '0'. How do I constrain it?

I get a syntax error for this piece code:

```
rand bit value;
bit x; // Has either 1 or 0 depending on external signal
constraint constraint_c { value dist { x := 3, ~x := 1};};
```

Comment: A conditional biased coin? Most likely you will need to chose (via say a mux) from two distributions one biased for 1 and one biased for 0. Other than that I know no specifics.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an if-else in a constraint

```
rand bit value;
bit x;
constraint c {
    if(x)
       value dist {1 := 3, 0 := 1};
    else
       value dist {1 := 1, 0 := 3};
}
```

Your weights can also be variables

```
int weight0, weight1;
 constraint c {
       value dist {1 := weight1, 0 := weight0};

// set before calling randomize
if (x) begin
    weight1 = 3; weight0 =1;
end else begin
    weight1 = 1; weight0 =3;
end
```

Or expressions

```
 constraint c {
           value dist {1 := x?3:1, 0 := x?1:3};
```